# svcutil /sc does not generate Task async methods

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

When I run `svcutil` with no arguments, I get by default two methods, one sync and one Task async, as below:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IConsultaDisponibilidade/RetornaDados", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConsultaDisponibilidade/RetornaDadosResponse")]
string RetornaDados(FastServices.WsConsultaDisponibilidade.Componentes.PedidoEntity dadosPedido);

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IConsultaDisponibilidade/RetornaDados", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConsultaDisponibilidade/RetornaDadosResponse")]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> RetornaDadosAsync(FastServices.WsConsultaDisponibilidade.Componentes.PedidoEntity dadosPedido);
```

I'm doing my own thing with clients and channels though, and I don't want the extra code `svcutil` generates, so I run it with `svcutil /sc ...`.

The problem is, when I switch this on I only the synchronous method is created.

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IConsultaDisponibilidade/RetornaDados", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConsultaDisponibilidade/RetornaDadosResponse")]
string RetornaDados(FastServices.WsConsultaDisponibilidade.Componentes.PedidoEntity dadosPedido);
```

I haven't found a way to circumvent this in the options.

Is there even one?

There is `/a` but that will generate Begin/End async methods like this:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IConsultaDisponibilidade/RetornaDados", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConsultaDisponibilidade/RetornaDadosResponse")]
System.IAsyncResult BeginRetornaDados(FastServices.WsConsultaDisponibilidade.Componentes.PedidoEntity dadosPedido, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

string EndRetornaDados(System.IAsyncResult result);
```

I'd like to have the Task async method.

Any suggestions on how to keep contract generation but drop client and channel boilerplate automatically?

Comment: Maybe try `svcutil /sc /a`?  The `/a` will generate async and synchronous.

Comment: /a only generates Begin/End async versions. I want the Task async method.

Comment: but thanks, let me clarify that in the question